# How to access SharePoint web part properties?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I have created a feature for SharePoint 2007 that has a web part. I have added a custom property to the web part like so:

```
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[Category("My Custom Properties")]
[WebDisplayName("ServiceURL")]
[WebDescription("The URL for the Wcf service")]
public string ServiceURL { get; set; }
```

Along with this web part, I've added a custom page that the web part will have a link to. I would like to reference the web part property from the custom page, but I don't know where these properties are stored. I've tried to access it using the code below, but both property collections don't have any properties stored.

```
SPFeaturePropertyCollection spProperties = SPContext.Current.Site.Features[this.FeatureGuid].Properties;
```

or

```
SPFeaturePropertyCollection spProperties = SPContext.Current.Site.Features[this.FeatureGuid].Definition.Properties;
```

My question is how can I get a reference to the web part property from other pages?

Answer (score 0):

Custom properties are displayed under the WebPart property pane.

You'll find a sample from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174%28v=office.11%29.aspx) (Example from SharePoint 2003 but still working)